# Props Passing and getting NaN

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to pass props from my filtered items onto a state and create some sort of a "buying cart".
(as in, passing the price prop onto a state and render the sum of everything).

the result of what i've been trying to do is simply getting NaN for some reason and the page keeps on re-rendering when i click "Add".

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import ITEMDATA from "./Item_Data.json";

const StyledSearch = styled.form`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
`;

const StyledInput = styled.input`
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
`;

const Vendor = () => {
  const [itemInput, setItemInput] = useState("");
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const onClickHandler = (e, itemprice) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTotal(total + itemprice);
  };

  return (
    <StyledSearch>
      <p>{total}</p>
      <div>
        <StyledInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search Item..."
          value={itemInput}
          onChange={(e) => setItemInput(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      {total === 0 ? <div>Nothing to show.</div> : total}
      {itemInput && (
        <div>
          {ITEMDATA.filter((item) => {
            if (itemInput === "") {
              return item;
            } else if (
              item.item_name.toLowerCase().includes(itemInput.toLowerCase())
            ) {
              return item;
            }
          }).map((item) => {
            return (
              <p key={item.id}>
                {item.item_name}
                <br />
                {item.vendor_name}
                <br />
                {item.price}
                <br />
                <button onClick={onClickHandler} itemprice={item.price}>
                  Add
                </button>
              </p>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </StyledSearch>
  );
};

export default Vendor;
```

Would very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering, pass in the item price into the click handler for the button. Change

```
<button onClick={onClickHandler} itemprice={item.price}>
```

to

```
<button onClick={() => setTotal(total + item.price)}>
```

I don't see a `<form>`, so you don't need the `e.preventDefault()`, or the `onClickHandler` at all.

If you do have an ancestor form, you can do

```
<button
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTotal(total + item.price);
  }}
>
```

or make a higher-order function

```
const makeClickHandler = price => e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTotal(total + price);
};
```

```
<button onClick={makeClickHandler(item.price)}>
```